# WSACancelBlockingCall after work with TcpListener

Tags: c#

I have multi-thread TcpListener. It is start from button

```
    private void startServer_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Server = new Thread(ServerThread);
            Server.Start();
        }
```

method of ServerThread looks like:

```
  protected void ServerThread()
    {
        try
        {
            ....;
            serverListener = new TcpListener(localAddr, port);

                serverListener.Start();

                while (true)
                {
                    Application.DoEvents();
                    while (!serverListener.Pending()) Thread.Sleep(500);

                    ConnectionThread newconnection = new ConnectionThread(mainClient);
                }
            }
            catch (SocketException error)
            {
                .....;
            }
            finally
            {
                serverListener.Stop();
            }
        }
```

Here ConnectionThread class looks like:

```
  class ConnectionThread
        {
            public ConnectionThread(Action<object> methodWork)
            {
                ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(new WaitCallback(methodWork));
            }
        }
```

And here I have methodwork looks like:

```
  public void mainClient(object state)
        {
                TcpClient client = serverListener.AcceptTcpClient();
                NetworkStream stream = client.GetStream();

                Byte[] bytes = new Byte[25600000];
                String data = null;

                int i;
                while ((i = stream.Read(bytes, 0, bytes.Length)) != 0)
                {
                   ....
                }
                stream.Close();
                client.Close();
        }
```

And after all I have stop server button which looks like:

```
 private void stopServer_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Server.Abort();
            serverListener.Server.Close();
            serverListener.Stop();
        }
```

Everything works good. After work with tcplistener and try to stop it - it is stop in 1 sec and get error WSACancelBlockingError. I know that this error because I'm try to stop TcpListener from another Thread. But how I can solve this? Make Action<>? It is good decision?